# Why all menus in Windows are floating left with dual monitor?

Tags: windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors, gui, tablet

I'm using a tablet running Windows 8 with an external monitor and the second monitor as the main one. All menus are floating left. Is there a way to change this? My tablet is physically positioned on the right of the monitor.

[image: All menus floating left]

The big picture:
[image: Another screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Based on [Vinicius's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/537843/why-all-menus-in-windows-are-floating-left-with-dual-monitor#comment651758_538369) and the updated screen shot.

An application must have changed the default alignment of menu.

This setting can't be configured via Control Panel, yet Windows provides API to change it. And I've written [a simple application](https://iasoft.malyek.net/files/MenuAlignment.exe) which allows changing the alignment of menus, and shows the current alignment.

Run [MenuAlignment.exe](https://iasoft.malyek.net/files/MenuAlignment.exe), it will display the current status. Click **Yes** to change the alignment to the reverse setting:

[image: Menu Alignment: Menus are left-aligned]
[image: Menu Alignment: Menus are right-aligned]

And after changing the alignment, it displays confirmation:
[image: Menu Alignment: Menu alignment has been changed to left]

---

In the case on the screen shot, there's simply not enough space to display the menu to the right, and Windows displays the menu with left alignment then. Move your window farther to the left or right, and your menus will display normally.

It also happens in one monitor configuration too: if the menu can't be displayed with left-alignment because it would fall out of screen, the it will be right-positioned.

Windows will not split menus to span both monitors, it will position the popup menu so that it's fully displayed on one of the monitors. The reasoning for that is that monitors may be not side-by-side.

<sub>There's a system setting which controls the default menu alignment, it's not exposed through the UI yet it's available to applications.</sub>

Comment: hummm... that's not the case. I cropped the image. I'll update the question with another screenshot.

Comment: @Vinicius I updated my answer.